# Count current users on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to count current viewers on the particular page. I need this count to be stored in the DB. The main trouble is to clean up after user leaves the page.

Users are anonymous. Every active user sends AJAX-request every 5 seconds.

What's the best algorithm to do that? Any suggestions?

**UPD:** I'm trying to reduce amount of queries to the DB, so, I think, I don't *really* need to store that count in the DB while I can access it other way from the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't even think about storing this in database, your app will be incredibly slowed down.

So use Cache for this kind of operation.

To count the number of people, I'd say:

- assign a random ID to each anonymous user and store it in his session
- send the ID within your ajax call
- store an Array of Hashes in cache with `[{ :user_id, :latest_ping }, {} ]` (create a cache var for each page)
- delete the elements of the array which appear to be too old
- you've your solution: number of users = nb of elements in the array

Comment: Your solution is great and fits my needs nicely, but could you please tell me what's the best way to delete old elements from cache?

Comment: I'd use [delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) which is built_in. The contion would be based on the difference between the time stored and the current Time. You have to choose what is acceptable

Comment: So I have to run some task periodically in the background anyway?

Comment: Nope, you should do that just before you retrieve the count data.

Comment: This looks perfect. I'm guessing Redis will do nicely for the cache?

Comment: @LaurentGorse its one of the many solutions. I generally use memcached though

Comment: I'm implementing this solution and it strikes me that at a larger scale (not a problem right now let's be honest) iterating through the hashes at every data request may slow down the process? What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @LaurentGorse I agree, databases are better suited to handle large scale queries

Comment: @LaurentGorse a cool feature in redis is to let you retrieve the keys in a namespace, so if you expire them and count them, it could be very quick

Comment: Yep I'm looking at implementing that. One issue is that the namespace would be the video Id the viewer is currently on (so the setup would be: {video-id:user-id, timestamp}. And I'm wondering if I can call redis::namespace.new(:video-id) from a controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the users in the database somehow, you could store a `last_seen_at` field in the users table, and update that with `Time.now` for every AJAX request that user sends.

To display how many users you currently have, you can just perform a query such as:

```
@user_count = User.where("last_seen_at < ?", 5.seconds.ago).count
```

If you want to clean up old users, I suggest that you run some kind of cron job, or use the `whenever` gem, or something like that, to periodically delete all users that haven't been seen for some time.

Comment: How can you decently suggest to achieve this kind of query with a database?

Comment: Well, for starters he actually said that he _needed_ to store the count in the database, but yeah, your solution is way better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a model that contains a unique key (cookie-id or something) that you save or update with every AJAX heartbeat request.

You then have a session controller that could look like this:

```
def create
  ActiveUser.where(:cookie => params[:id]) || ActiveUser.new
  ActiveUser.cookie = prams[:id]
  ActiveUser.timestamp = Time.now
  ActiveUser.save
end
```

Your number of active users is then simply a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActiveUsers WHERE timestamp > NOW() - 5` or something like that.

Comment: How can you decently suggest to achieve this kind of query with a database?

Comment: I'm kinda trying to reduce amount of DB requests here, so this is not exactly what I need. But thanks.

Comment: Since rails has no in-process store you can either go for a DB or use redis or whatever .. 
Hitting a DB or hitting redis or hitting a cache item is then mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Frost is on the right track. There's the `#touch` method to update `last_seen_at`: `user.touch(:last_seen_at)`

But it would be even more efficient to just update the user without having to fetch the model from the database:

```
> User.update_all({:last_seen_at => Time.now}, {:id => params[:user_id})
SQL (3.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_seen_at" = '2011-11-17 12:37:46.863660' WHERE "users"."id" = 27
=> 1
```